# How can I programmatically deactivate multiple user accounts?

Tags: 8, users

I have tried the following code, but something doesn't work, could you please help. I need to deactivate several accounts at once, if they satisfy the conditions:

```
$ids = \Drupal::entityQuery('user')
  ->condition('roles', 'student')
  ->condition('field_school_id', $node_id)
  ->execute();
$users = User::loadMultiple($ids);


$storage_handler = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage("user");

foreach($users as $user){
  $entity = $storage_handler->load($user->id());
  $entity->set("status", 0);
  $storage_handler->save($entity); // THE PROBLEM IS IN THIS LINE
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you load the users two times. In the foreach loop you already have the loaded entity available in `$user`.

Change your foreach loop to look like this and it should work:

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
  $user->set("status", 0);
  $user->save();
}
```

You can also remove the `$storageHandler` since you don't use that any more.